# My bangla keyboard layout does not match the physical keyboard

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard-layout, unicode

**Steps:**

- `Settings > Region & Language > Add Bangla to Input Sources`

[image: Add Region & Language]

- selected `bn`.

Here, is the `gkbd-keyboard-display -l bn` output.

[image: Bangla Keyboard Layout]

In LibreOffice Writer, when I work with bangla fonts supplied with Linux, few keys give different glyph. They do not match my physical bangla keyboard. Specially <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> should be swapped when using `bn`.

First, I was confused whether it is a Keyboard Manufacturer issue or a Linux Issue. If you look at bottom row <kbd>Z,X...</kbd> you will see, there are 11 keys. As far I know, all standard english or bangla keyboards have 10 keys there.

In my case, the two keys after <kbd>Shift L</kbd> should be replaced by another key.

For Bangla Input Methods I think Linux Use Avro or OpenBangla Keyboard. How can I find out which one Linux is Using?

How can I fix this issue? At this moment a temporary solution would be good enough. But If I want to create a bug report, whom should I contact? Where should I create the issue?

Comment: I have zero knowledge of this particular language. But I can remember that, in the past, the keyboard layout for bengali (as well as several others of the kind) was generated per default using /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ **bd** but several other bengali layouts were indeed made available in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ **in** file which were not exposed as possible solutions. Quite old related post : https://arrbee.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/xkb-keyboards-on-ibus/ . If it helps (Suggesting a solution using xkeyboard-config )

Comment: @MC68020 I am using Ubuntu based OS. My PC does not seem to have `xkeyboard-config`. How can I switch the layout?

Comment: I cannot tell the application you are using from the image you posted in OP. Try adding india. Maybe you'll get choice between variations.

Comment: My keyboard layout is "Bijoy". I can not find this. The closest I found in mentioned in the question (in that case i have to swap two keys and replace two keys with one).

Comment: Could this help ? https://archive.org/compress/Bijoy-Linux/formats=ZIP&file=/Bijoy-Linux.zip

Comment: @MC68020 I checked. I think the instruction is outdated. For example, `/usr/share/m17n` does not exist in my ubuntu. Moreover, there is no file with the extension `.mim` in my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP Here. The problem is solved.

I think Linux use "Probhat Unicode" by default.

```
$ localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
$ localectl list-x11-keymap-variants bd
probhat
```

In Bangladesh the keyboard layout is [UniJoy Unicode](https://ekushey.org/keyboards/). To use this:

```
$ sudo apt install m17n-db
$ dpkg -L m17n-db | grep unijoy
/usr/share/m17n/bn-unijoy.mim
/usr/share/m17n/icons/bn-unijoy.png
```

Now [Restart ibus](https://askubuntu.com/q/389903/598062). To do that I used `ibus restart`. Just to make sure ibus keeps running, use `ibus-daemon -d`.

Now go to `Settings > Region & Language > Add Bangla (unijoy (m17n)) to Input Sources`

Thats  It!

Comment: indeed happy you managed to find your way and +1 for that… forgetting you had been whining about the installation of the m17n database as part of your OP's comments…;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xmodmap` from *x11-xserver-utils.deb* package (debian - ubuntu should be similar). Create a *.xmodmaprc* file and map the keys at you liking.

Read the manpage: `man xmodmap`

Your current table is printed with `xmodmap -pke`

With `xev` from *x11-utils.deb* you'll find the keycodes.

I have a `.xsessionrc` in home with:

```
if [ -f ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
fi
```

Comment: Where can I find my current .Xmodmap file for bangla. It will be easier to edit that.

Comment: just to be clear, the remap should only be for bangla and not english. One more thing, where should I put the `.Xmodmap` file.

Comment: There is no default `.Xmodmap` nor `.xmodmaprc`. Fead the changed keys with `xmodmap -e "keys"`. (see examples in manpage)

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please check. If you have something along that line, I will be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you found your solution!

Comment: xmodmap is deprecated. Apparently Wayland and Ubuntu based distros uses `xkb`. If you kindly give a solution based on that, I will be glad to accept your answer (at least it directed me to the right direction). The probhat is in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd`. I think we can add more layouts there.

Answer (score -2):

*Although the problem is solved by the OP himself, nonetheless I am posting one of the solutions that I came up with.*

To determine which Bangla input method your Linux system is using, you can try the following steps:

1. Open the LibreOffice Writer
2. In the menu bar, go to Tools > Options.
3. In the Options window, select the Language Settings > Language tab.
4. In the Default languages for documents section, select the Bengali
   (Bangladesh) or Bengali (India) language, depending on your
   location.
5. Click OK to save the changes.
6. In the menu bar, go to Tools > Options again.
7. In the Options window, select the Language Settings > Language tab.
8. In the Input methods section, you should see the name of the input
   method that is currently being used for Bangla text input. This is
   likely to be either Avro or OpenBangla Keyboard.

To fix the issue with the keys not matching your physical keyboard, you can try changing the keyboard layout in the input method settings. In LibreOffice Writer, go to Tools > Options, select the Language Settings > Language tab, and then click on the Details button next to the input method. This should open a window where you can select the correct keyboard layout and save the changes.

Comment: That last paragraph should really be replaced by actual links to the relevant resources, or be deleted as it just asks the user to google it themselves.