# How to fix Uni Gitanjali keyboard layout for bangla?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-method

I use MX21.3 + KDE plasma(v5.20.5). For my native language bangla,
I prefer uni gitanjali layout.

After I enable it from the “system settings”, I run into a problem.
It doesn’t have a আ key. Instead, it showed two এ key.
Pressing the qwerty *s* key should generate **আ** not **এ**.

Is it a known problem? Without switching to another layout
how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to sign your questions.

Comment: Please cf to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726692/my-bangla-keyboard-layout-does-not-match-the-physical-keyboard (the question, the first comment from mine and the answer. Would this help ?